# Increment a value in range ( one column ) with if and multicriteria - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I try to loop on each row and check for U & AA values and set value of the Y value of the same row based on the folowing criteria :

J value is 1
If AA value is : "TEST" then Y value is set ( j + 1 )
If U value is : "33" then Y value is set ( j + 1 ) then J = j + 1
If AA value isn't "TEST" & U value isn't "33" then Y value is set ( j )

Here my code

```
function RowNumbre() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Test');
  var range = sheet.getRange("AA:AA200").getValues();
for (var i=2; i < range.length; i++) {
  var j = 1;
  var value = sheet.getRange("Y"+i);
  var value2 = sheet.getRange("U"+i).getValue();
  var value3 = sheet.getRange("AA"+i).getValue();
  if(value2 === "33"){
    value.setValue(j+1);
    j= j+1;
  }
  else if(value3 === "TEST"){
value.setValue(j+1);
  }
  else {
    value.setValue(j);
  }
}
}
```

The code don't work at all and it's look like there is a huge lag ( for the moment, a "1" is added to each cell on Y each 2-3 minutes and it wont stop.

Comment: Use textfinder instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function RowNumbre() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  const rg1=sh.getRange("Y1:Y200");
  var vs1=rg1.getValues();
  const rg2=sh.getRange("U1:U200");
  var vs2=rg2.getValues();
  const rg3=sh.getRange("AA1:AA200");
  var vs3=rg3.getValues();
  var sv=1;
  vs1.forEach(function(v,i){if(vs2[i][0]==33){v[0]=sv++;}else if(vs3[i][0]=="TEST"){v[0]=sv+1;}else{v[0]=sv;}});
  rg1.setValues(vs1);
}
```